# Multiple audio players but only first working

Tags: javascript

The problem is that when i have 2 or more players on html page i can only play music in the first player and the rest wont work.

my customized HTML5 audio player:

```
<audio id="music" preload="true">
    <source src="music/interlude.mp3">
</audio>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="audioplayer">
        <button id="pButton" class="play"></button>
        <div id="timeline">
            <div id="playhead"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and js for this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

var music = document.getElementById('music'); // id for audio element
var duration; // Duration of audio clip
var pButton = document.getElementById('pButton'); // play button
var playhead = document.getElementById('playhead'); // playhead
var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline'); // timeline

// timeline width adjusted for playhead
var timelineWidth = timeline.offsetWidth - playhead.offsetWidth;

// play button event listenter
pButton.addEventListener("click", play);

// timeupdate event listener
music.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate, false);

// makes timeline clickable
timeline.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    moveplayhead(event);
    music.currentTime = duration * clickPercent(event);
}, false);

// returns click as decimal (.77) of the total timelineWidth
function clickPercent(event) {
    return (event.clientX - getPosition(timeline)) / timelineWidth;

}

// makes playhead draggable
playhead.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);

// Boolean value so that audio position is updated only when the playhead is released
var onplayhead = false;

// mouseDown EventListener
function mouseDown() {
    onplayhead = true;
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveplayhead, true);
    music.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeUpdate, false);
}

// mouseUp EventListener
// getting input from all mouse clicks
function mouseUp(event) {
    if (onplayhead == true) {
        moveplayhead(event);
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveplayhead, true);
        // change current time
        music.currentTime = duration * clickPercent(event);
        music.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeUpdate, false);
    }
    onplayhead = false;
}
// mousemove EventListener
// Moves playhead as user drags
function moveplayhead(event) {
    var newMargLeft = event.clientX - getPosition(timeline);

    if (newMargLeft >= 0 && newMargLeft <= timelineWidth) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = newMargLeft + "px";
    }
    if (newMargLeft < 0) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    }
    if (newMargLeft > timelineWidth) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = timelineWidth + "px";
    }
}

// timeUpdate
// Synchronizes playhead position with current point in audio
function timeUpdate() {
    var playPercent = timelineWidth * (music.currentTime / duration);
    playhead.style.marginLeft = playPercent + "px";
    if (music.currentTime == duration) {
        pButton.className = "";
        pButton.className = "play";
    }
}

//Play and Pause
function play() {
    // start music
    if (music.paused) {
        music.play();
        // remove play, add pause
        pButton.className = "";
        pButton.className = "pause";
    } else { // pause music
        music.pause();
        // remove pause, add play
        pButton.className = "";
        pButton.className = "play";
    }
}

// Gets audio file duration
music.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
    duration = music.duration;
}, false);

// getPosition
// Returns elements left position relative to top-left of viewport
function getPosition(el) {
    return el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
}

/* DOMContentLoaded*/
});
```

i belive the problem is somewhere in the js code but i cant figure out where.
i took the code form [here](http://alexkatz.me/posts/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-javascript/)

Comment: Where's the second player?

Comment: Whenever u want it to be. I've just posted full audio player block that can be duplicated after another.

Comment: Problem is if you use the exact same code, it's just going to the first one with the the id of `music`. You can only have one id per page. Having 3 `#music` confuses poor overwhelmed JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you're using a **lot** of IDs. When the "first of something" works on a page, usually it's IDs that are causing the issue.

Change all of your IDs for your `<audio>` players to `class` attributes. You will also need to update your JavaScript as well, from something like this:

```
var music = document.getElementById('music');
music.addEventListener(...
```

To something more like this:

```
var music = document.querySelectorAll(".music"); // class="music"
for (var i = 0; i < music.length; i++) {
  music[i].addEventListener(...
```

You should find that this will work for you.

Comment: any chance u paste full reworked code?
I have little knowlege about js and im not the author ot this code.